# Passing array by reference as template argument works with gcc and clang but not with msvc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I started learning about templates and `constexpr` in C++. Then I wrote the following program that compiles with `gcc` and `clang`, but not with `msvc`. [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hdbnhrcTa).

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
template<std::size_t N, const bool (&ref)[N]> void func()
{
       
       constexpr int j = ref[0]; //rejected by msvc but compiles with clang and gcc
}
int main()
{
    static constexpr bool arr[] = {true, false};;
    func<2, arr>();
  
}
```

As we can see the above program is rejected by `msvc` but compiles fine with `gcc` and `clang`. I don't know the correct behavior according to the standard. So, which compiler is correct here according to the c++ standard?

Here is the msvc error:

```
<source>(5): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(9): note: failure was caused by unevaluable pointer value
<source>(10): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void func<2,& bool const * const `main'::`2'::arr>(void)' being compiled
```

Comment: Please make your questions *self-contained*. If you post questions regarding build errors, then copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question itself (copy-paste *as text*). Links to external sites could become broken, disappear or their contents might change, making your question rather useless. Remember that this site isn't only to help you right now, but also others that might have the same or a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Can be simplified to simple reference: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P4fs5EzYM)

Comment: From template onlly, `ref[0]` is not guaranteed to be compile-time value (we don't have pointer/reference to constexpr).

Comment: I don't know whether this is actually well-specified, but assuming that "_at a point P_" in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#4 refers to the point of instantiation of the constant expression, then I guess it is IFNDR because https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.8 would apply depending on which point-of-instantiation of the function is considered, applying for the one preceding `main`, but not for the one at end of the translation unit.

Comment: Or if a reference non-type template parameter is considered a variable, then https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.12 applies directly.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should be, to my knowledge, fully equivalent to original one. And it compiles correctly even on `msvc`!

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N, const bool (&ref)[N]> void func()
{
       constexpr int j = ref[0];;
}

constexpr bool arr[] = {true, false};;

int main()
{
    func<2, arr>();
  
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6srEq37qz

AFAIK variable in global scope should be initialized before program starts, while static in a function should be initialized when the control first reaches the scope.

However, I don't think this should affect our `constexpr` case in any way - but it may have caused difficulties for the compiler developers.

So my conclusion is that we are dealing with some weirdness of `msvc` that is not due to The Standard.